# Unable to install anything in NAS drive

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have the WD PR2100. I have signed onto the root OS via SSH and I am unable to locate my primary linux OS name. This is what I have so far:

```
root@NAS01  # uname -a
OUTPUT## Linux NAS01 4.14.22 #1 SMP Wed Apr 27 07:00:16 UTC 2022 Build-34 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@NAS01  # cd home/root/extapps/aptget
root@NAS01 aptget # wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.5.2_arm64.deb
root@NAS01 aptget # dpkg -i apt_2.5.2_arm64.deb
OUTPUT##dpkg: can't extract control file
root@NAS01 aptget # wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.5.2_amd64.deb
root@NAS01 aptget # dpkg -i apt_2.5.2_amd64.deb
OUTPUT## dpkg: can't extract control file
```

Nothing seems to work. My main aim is to be able to use `apt-get` and some other functions. I believe if I simply knew my operating system I would be able to download the correct application.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe if I simply knew my operating system I would be able to download the correct application.

That's a fallacy. Simple as that - to build an application for an embedded os like the custom Linux that's probably running on your router, you need an SDK - a toolchain containing compatible compilers, linkers, development headers and linker scripts to target that machine.

So, no, it's not that simple, and the name of the OS won't help you very much; it's bound to be some internal name of something derived from a custom distro built specifically for that hardware.

Your whole attempt to run Debian tooling on this very likely non-Debian system hence is doomed.